# Why am i getting C++ double data type error when doubles have a precision of 15 digits

Tags: c++

```
#include<iomanip>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
   double b = 1.9876543212987 ;
   cout<<"double: "<<setprecision(12)<<b<<endl;
}
```

This is the code and the ouput is: **double: 1.9876543213** It should be 3212 at the end. Why does this happen with certain numbers and not with others.

If i set b to `double b = 3.91234823929;` with the same precision it gives me a correct value. Need some help from the c++ pros.

Comment: Looks like it's rounding to the nearest significant digit.

Comment: Why should it be `3212` at the end?  the following digit is `9` and since that is greater than `5`, you round up the `2` to a `3`.

Comment: Also see the examples here https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setprecision  Specifically `std::setprecision(10)` and `max precision:`   results

Comment: I understood the rounding up part but i don't get why it's only 11 digits when i set the precision to be 12? Thanks for the answers btw was not expecting it to be that quick.

Comment: Also is there a way to stop it from rounding up digits?

Comment: @TheRealestDeal The question you asked was about "the rounding up part", not the "only 11 digits" part, as ending in `3212` would not change the number of digits. If your question was about the number of digits, you should have expected either `32129` or `32130` at the end, not `3212`. Please make sure you ask the question you intend to ask.

Comment: How would you want it to round `1.999999999999999` with a 12 digit precision? It needs a precision of 16 to display `1.999....` and any precision lower than that will display `2`. Would you consider that wrong?

Comment: Because I/O of floating point in C++ rounds to the nearest value, it doesn't simply truncate.   `1.9876543212987` to 12 significant figures would (without rounding) would be `1.98765432129`.   The next digit is an `8`, so that `1.98765432129` (rounding to the nearest) needs to be rounded up, which gives `1.98765432130`.

Comment: Also, `setprecision()` controls the (well) precision of the value output.  By default, any trailing zeros on the output are omitted - `setprecision()` doesn't affect that.  You can control that using the `setwidth()` manipulator -  set width to 12, and trailing zeros would be used to ensure 12 digits are output.

Comment: @TheRealestDeal also note that a common mistake people make with `setprecision` is expecting it to set the number of digits after the decimal place. [That is not what it does](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/precision). Digits before the decimal are also included in the precision. If you want 12 digits after the decimal, format the value to a `std::string` first, using default or higher precision, and then truncate/padd the `string` as needed.

Answer (score 1):

`1.9876543212987` to twelve decimal places is `1.987654321230`. The trailing zero is then dropped, so you get `1.98765432123`. That explains why you only get 11 decimal places.

There is no easy way to stop it rounding up digits. After all the closest possible value is what most people want. Seems that would you should do is to write the output to a string at maximum precision, then do some string manipulation on the final digits. That way you can leave in trailing zeros, truncate instead of round etc.